# How to uplaod a file in chunks using indy?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, idhttp

I am getting problem in uploading files using "OpenDrive API". I can connect and do other stuffs. 
Here is the developer api:[OpenDrive Api](https://dev.opendrive.com/api/explorer/#!/upload/createOpen_file_upload_post)

Using Http Analyzer I can see operation like Createupload, Openupload and Closeupload but I observe that there is no packet transferring during uploading(For example: 5mb of upload transfer).. I cant figure out How to handle chunksize, chunk_offset while post.

Here are my codes:-

```
procedure TUploadThread.Execute;
var
 Filename : string;  
 CreateFileParams : TStrings;  
 OpenFileParams :TStrings;
 CloseFileParams : TStrings;
 JResponse : string;
 FileID : string; 
 TempLocation : string;
 JFileCreateObject :ISuperObject;  
 JFileOpenObject : ISuperObject;

begin
  filename := ExtractFileName(frmMain.OpenDialog.FileName);

  try
    CreateFileParams := TStringList.Create;

    CreateFileParams.Add('session_id=' + frmMain.SessionKey);
    CreateFileParams.Add('folder_id=' + frmMain.CurrentFolderID);
    CreateFileParams.Add('file_name=' + FileName);
    CreateFileParams.Add('file_size=' + frmMain.UploadFileSize);
    CreateFileParams.Add('access_folder_id=Public');

    try
      { Try To Create An Instance Of File In The Server }
      JResponse := frmMain.HttpClient.Post('https://dev.opendrive.com/api/v1/upload/create_file.json',CreateFileParams);

      { Now We Have Got FileID & DIR_Update Time from ResponseFileCreate in JSON Format. Lets Parse FileID For later use }
      JFileCreateObject := SO(JResponse);
      FileID := JFileCreateObject['FileId'].AsString; { Here we got FileID}

      OpenFileParams := TStringList.Create;
      OpenFileParams.Add('session_id=' + frmMain.SessionKey);
      OpenFileParams.Add('file_id=' + FileID);
      OpenFileParams.Add('file_size=' + frmMain.UploadFileSize);
      OpenFileParams.Add('access_folder_id=Public');

      try
        Sleep(1000); { Wait For 1 sec Then Perform Another Request }
        JResponse := frmMain.HttpClient.Post('https://dev.opendrive.com/api/v1/upload/open_file_upload.json', OpenFileParams);
        { Now Parse TempLocation From The Json Response In Jresponse }
        JFileOpenObject := SO(JResponse);
        TempLocation := JFileOpenObject['TempLocation'].AsString;

        { Finally, Lets pass the parameters to the close Upload session }
        CloseFileParams := TStringList.Create;
        CloseFileParams.Add('session_id=' + frmMain.SessionKey);
        CloseFileParams.Add('file_id=' + FileID);
        CloseFileParams.Add('temp_location=' + TempLocation);
        CloseFileParams.Add('file_size=' + frmMain.UploadFileSize);
        CloseFileParams.Add('access_folder_id=Public');

         Sleep(1000); { Wait for 1 sec Then Perform Another Request }
         JResponse :=  frmMain.HttpClient.Post('https://dev.opendrive.com/api/v1/upload/close_file_upload.json', CloseFileParams);

        { If Nothing Exception raises, File Is Uploaded..Wait 1 Sec and Reload The Folder }
        frmMain.btnRefresh.Click;

      finally
      end;

    except
      ShowMessage('An Error Occured While Uplaoding File(s).Please Try Aagin');
    end;
  finally
    CreateFileParams.Free;
    OpenFileParams.Free;
    CloseFileParams.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the API then you should be using the following two API's as well.

https://dev.opendrive.com/api/explorer/#!/upload/createResumable_post

and

https://dev.opendrive.com/api/explorer/#!/upload/createUpload_file_chunk_post

you might be able to get away without the createResumable call but not the upload file chunk one.

Your process should probably be something like this:

```
CreateFile
Open File Upload
Loop
  Upload File Chunk
End Loop
Close File Upload
```

Comment: Yes, Create_Upload_File_Chunk_Post is required but I am unable to handle this post. The parameters required are "Chunk_Offset" and "Chunk_size". How do I post them?
Any code segment or example will be appreciated.

Comment: They are sent as POST data just like your other fields. You are creating the chunks, so you should know how large your chunks are, and what the file offset of each chunk is. What is hard to understand about that exactly? Open the file with a `TFileStream` and loop through it until you reach EOF. For each loop iteration, set the `chunk_offset` to the current `TFileStream.Position`, then read a block of data from the file and set the `chunk_size` to the number of bytes read, then POST that block, then repeat.